# RegEx How to retrieve values from nested XML tags

Tags: regex

I need to retrieve values for APPNAME and Host Tags using RegEx.

Desired outcome: TEST Web Server1, SERVERWEB1
                 TEST Web Server2, SERVERWEB2

Any directions or guidance greatly appreciated:

```
<AppProperties>
      <Text>Test Web Server</Text>
    <ProgramGroup>TEST PROGRAM Group</ProgramGroup>
    <APPNAME>TEST Web Server1</APPNAME>
    <Hosts>
      <HostbyNetwork>
        <NetworkID>Default</NetworkID>
        <Host>SERVERWEB1</Host>
      </HostbyNetwork>
    </Hosts>
</AppProperties>

<AppProperties>
      <Text>Test Web Server</Text>
    <ProgramGroup>TEST PROGRAM Group</ProgramGroup>
    <APPNAME>TEST Web Server2</APPNAME>
    <Hosts>
      <HostbyNetwork>
        <NetworkID>Default</NetworkID>
        <Host>SERVERWEB2</Host>
      </HostbyNetwork>
    </Hosts>
</AppProperties>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What environment are you working in? (general idea is - *don't*, use a proper parser instead, whenever possible)

Comment: so far I am only able to get value for one tag, <APPNAME\b[^>]*>(.*?)</APPNAME>

Comment: Can you answer the other question? What environment are you working in? There's probably a more elegant way than a regex

Comment: RegEx is one of the available parser on the application I am working (service mapping by service now)

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't mean it's the parser you *have* to use - what language are you writing the application in?

Answer (score 0):

Something to start with:

```
/
NAME>
([^<]+) # Match 1: anything but '<'
.+?
Host>
([^<]+) # Match 2: anything but '<'
/xs # Ignore pattern whitespace, dot matches newline
```

... ?